# initialize vector of pair of (bitset,int)

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair, std-bitset

when initializing with

```
vector<pair< int,bitset<p> > > arr;
arr.push_back(make_pair(x,y));
```

but I am gettig error:

‘pair’ cannot appear in a constant-expression

```
vector<pair< int,bitset<p> > > arr;
```

how to make a vector of pair of bitset,int?

Comment: Missing namespace qualification (`std::pair<...>`) and/or `#include <utility>`?

Comment: none of those errors. Used both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like "p" here is not constant. I tried the following and it works:

```
const int p = 16;
vector<pair<int,bitset<p> >> v;
bitset<p> b = 0xfa2;
v.push_back(make_pair(10, b));
```